# Can we simplify this result?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration

I was evaluating 
$$I=\int_0^1\ln (1+x)\ln ^{n-1}x\frac{\text{d}x}{x}$$
I did it with series:
$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}\int_0^1x^{k-1}\ln ^{n-1}x\text{d}x$$
$$=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{n+1}}$$
$$=(-1)^{n-1}(1-2^{-n})(n-1)!\zeta(n+1)$$
Is there a simpler form or method?

Comment: If $n$ is an odd integer, then the $\zeta(n+1)$ can be replaces with the usual Bernoulli number and $\pi^{n+1}$, but otherwise this looks like it's about as far as you can go.

Comment: What is $\ln^{n-1}x$? $\ln(\ln(\dots(\ln(\ln x)))$ with $n-1$ $\ln$?

Comment: @PatrickLi : That is just power

Comment: Please summarize the comments as an answer and accept it to close the issue.